# How to change the values in the string between the letters

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I have string something like `@"goodhouse=30&app=60&val=30askldkla"`
How can I found the value 30 between house= and &, and change it on 50?

Comment: i have tried `[str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"30" withString:@"60"
                               options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];` but it doesn't good if there are the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if ([yourString rangeOfString:@"30"].location==NSNotFound)
 {
    yourString = [yourString stringByReplaceOccurenceOfString:@"30" withString@"60"];

}

Answer (score 4):

You can find a range between **house=** and **&** string using `NSRange`. And if range exists, then change the string which you want.

Comment: it's bad because if the range thange i need all time to count it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
string=@"30";
str=[str stringByReplaceOccurenceOfString:string withString@"50"];
```

EDIT:-
try like this,

```
NSString *test = [dateandtime stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(10,2) withString:@"50"];
```

Comment: i try it but the problem if there are two string with 30. it make 50 for all of them but i need only for one

Comment: i wrote about it upper that using nsrange is bad because if string will be dynamic i all times need to count the range

Comment: If there is another answer that i can try.

Comment: if other than 30 is placed in between those then wt you want to do at that time?

Comment: 30 will be static. so i need to found the value between house= and &app and change it.